# What do they mean and what are the implications when they say that a case was posted for "orders"

Tags: india, process

> The Lokayukta Court on Monday **posted for orders to October 4 a
>   case** filed against former prime minister H D Deve Gowda and four
>   former chief ministers, for helping alleged land grabbing by Nandi
>   Infrastructure Corridor Enterprises (NICE

Hearings by the court are held regularly and the case moves through various stages - orders are passed at every hearing and entered into the *Order Sheet* - so why do they have a special day for "Orders"? What happens on this auspicious occasion and what are the implications?

Comment: In what jurisdiction is this court? Why do you think this is a general feature of common law, and not something specific to local procedures?

Comment: It has a State jurisdiction (i suspect - my knowledge is very limited): that is, each state passes an Act to create the legal creature called the 'Lokayukta' http://lokayukta.kar.nic.in/karnataka_lokayukta_act.htm The reason I tagged it common law is because  "The application of common law has been overarching in the Indian context; it has been enshrined in the Indian legal system over the space of two centuries by the English to the point that one can’t allocate an individual identity to Indian jurisprudence." http://blog.ipleaders.in/common-law-apply-india/

Comment: Ok, so it's *in India*. That's what I was asking. Although Indian law comes from common law, it's possible that this particular procedure is specific to India.

Comment: so what you are saying is that this 'order' stuff is part of 'court room procedure' and not part of law/act?

Comment: I don't know. It's possible. Also, even if it is part of Indian law, that wouldn't necessarily mean it has anything to do with common law.